# why git skip username & password typing when using http protocol

Tags: ruby, git, http, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I set up a git http server, using rails. Very similar to [GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq).

Because of the same Gem [grack](https://github.com/gitlabhq/grack) we were using.

The only diff is Grack::Auth.valid? method, it just authorize user's username & password.

the same route ,the same Gem, but **why git skip username & password typing** when I enter 
git clone http://domain.com/project.git to clone a repo.

Is anybody can tell me how can I solve this problem. Very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that Git had already cached those credentials, using a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

The other possibility is that the authentication mechanism on the server side was not properly setup (Grack in 2012, [gitlab-workhorse](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-workhorse#gitlab-workhorse) now)